# how to get count and percentage comparing two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, percentage

I have two tables one from last year and the current year one.

I need to get the total count of each table then compare and get the percentage of last year count and then group them by ID.

Table2012

```
ID  Cate
1     a
1     b
1     c
2     a
2     b
2     c
3     c
3     e
```

Table2013

```
ID   Cate
1     a
1     b
2     a
2     b
2     c
3     c
3     e
2     r
2     t
3     d
3     g
```

Required Report Result

```
ID   total2012    total2013    percentage
1       3              2            66%
2       3              5           167%
3       2              4           200%
```

Thank You in advance

Jason

Comment: Why have separate tables, rather than a single table with a `year` column?

Comment: We have to use table for each year because the data repeat itself each year

Comment: @eggyal Yeah, I'm suggesting the same idea as yours. I have answer it below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.total2012,
       b.total2013,
       (b.total2013 / a.total2012 * 100) AS percentage
FROM
    (SELECT id, Count(*) AS total2012
     FROM Table2012
     GROUP BY id) a,
    (SELECT id, Count(*) AS total2013
     FROM Table2013
     GROUP BY id) b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

### Edit

This works by first grouping the entries by `id˙ in each table and counting the grouped rows. After that, it joins those two results and selects it into a single result set, while at the same time calculating the percentage.

Apparently this doesn't work on very old MySQL versions (which didn't support subselects)

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.total2012' in 'field list'

Comment: am using MySql version 4.01

Comment: 4.01? whoa, that's like... 10 years old?

Comment: I know bu the my provider would not upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This answer is edited from Carko's answer.

TableData

```
ID    Cate    Year
1     a       2012
1     b       2012
1     c       2012
2     a       2012
2     b       2012
2     c       2012
3     c       2012
3     e       2012
1     a       2013
1     b       2013
2     a       2013
2     b       2013
2     c       2013
3     c       2013
3     e       2013
2     r       2013
2     t       2013
3     d       2013
3     g       2013
```

**Edit** **
This SQL is provided by eggyal (see comment below)
See it in >> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8522/1/0

This is a better SQL Statement:

```
SELECT   ID,
         SUM(Year=2012) AS total2012,
         SUM(Year=2013) AS total2013,
         100*SUM(Year=2013)/SUM(Year=2012) AS percentage
FROM     TableData
GROUP BY ID
```

**End of Edit** **

Below is the original SQL statement in this answer which is very much not efficient. xD

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.total2012,
       b.total2013,
       (b.total2013 / a.total2012 * 100) AS 'percentage'
FROM
    (SELECT ID, Count(*) AS total2012
     FROM `TableData` WHERE `Year` = 2012
     GROUP BY ID) a,
    (SELECT ID, Count(*) AS total2013
     FROM `TableData` WHERE `Year` = 2013
     GROUP BY ID) b
WHERE a.ID= b.ID
```

Comment: With this schema, one can simply do `SELECT ID, SUM(Year=2012) AS total2012, SUM(Year=2013) AS total2013, 100*SUM(Year=2013)/SUM(Year=2012) AS percentage FROM TableData GROUP BY ID`.  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8522/1/0).

Comment: @eggyal Hi, yours solution is better. Mine is not so efficient. XD. I have updated it into the answer.